# Microsoft Excel - Formula/Function to Parse out information to columns in a cell separated by '|'

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am working with a CSV export of product ordering information.  Column A contains the transaction ID and the problematic Column B is formatted like this:

product_name:Survival Pack|product_option_name:(1) MEGA Survival Pack|quantity:1|price:15.0|total:15.0;product_name:Weather Hippo Sticker|product_option_name:(5) Weather Hippo Stickers|quantity:1|price:2.0|total:2.0;product_name:Waldo Hippo Sticker|product_option_name:(5) Waldo Hippo Sticker|quantity:1|price:2.0|total:2.0

Is there a formula I can use that would break the product, quantity and price out into separate columns?

Thanks for any help, not looking forward to doing this manually.

Comment: Is all this material in a single cell ??

Comment: Are the `:` or the `|` separating the data columns? Or both? It is difficult to know with the way you formatted the question.

Comment: `Text to columns` is a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this would be the following.

First save the data into a text file (text only). Then open the text file in Excel and the import function will come up. Choose 'Delimited' and then choose the other box and type "|"(its above my forward slash on my computer. looks like two upright dashes on the key). click next then end and excel will import into columns.

However, you may have some cleaning to do because the heading words will go into that cell as well as the data. Instead of any formulas, I would use find and replace (CTRL H). It does the work much quicker to remove the headings. I am assuming you don't want any of the words left of the ": ".

So I would use "*: " in your find box and leave the replace box empty. That will delete everything left of the ":" and I included a space so you delete the space after the ":" as well. Customize that to what you actually want.

This is a very fast way to get rid of data you don't need.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($B1,"|",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]